# Comments on "Concurrency in Practice"

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
@ThreadSafe
public class SynchronizedInteger {
    @GuardedBy("this") private int value;
    public synchronized int get() { return value; }
    public synchronized void set(int value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

The book says:

> A good way to think about volatile variables is to imagine that they behave roughly like the SynchronizedInteger class
>   in Listing 3.3, replacing reads and writes of the volatile variable with calls to get and set.
>   ...
>   This analogy is not exact; the memory visibility effects of SynchronizedInteger are actually slightly stronger than those of volatile variables. See
>   Chapter 16.

I checked chapter 16, but didn't find an exact answer - how exactly the memory visibility guarantees are stronger?

Comment: Suggest you rephrase this. Make it a question that stands alone. Add the reference to Concurrency In Practice later on, to show why you are interested in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is that `volatile` creates a happens-before relationship between a write to the `volatile` variable and a subsequest read from it, whereas `synchronized` creates happens-before relationships between an unlock and a subsequent lock.

So, in the case of `SynchronizedInteger` happens-before relationship is created between any consequent operations with `SychrozniedInteger` (i.e. `get()` and `set()` calls), and it doesn't matter whether they are reads or writes. It differs from the behaviour of `volatile int` that provide happens-before only between a write and a consequent read.

Actually I can't imagine any meaningful example to illustrate this difference, so that these behaviours really differ only slightly.